# cura shows different Z heights

Tags: ultimaker-cura, blender

Cura v2.5.0
I've been working in Blender for some time, so I have experience with exporting stl from it with exact size and I had no scale issues with slicing.
But today cura showed a strange thing.
These are 3dBenchy and a stretched cube which are supposed to have 45mm height, also "boundary boxes" are turned on to show that there is no flying geometry.

[image]

As you can see below cura shows same size visually but different in numbers.
[image]

And if I scale the ship inside the cura it will look like this
(low reputation) `http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2017/08/01/0001/2747/88763/63/969fe8bc67.jpg`

Does anyone know if I screwed up the model somehow or can it be considered as a bug?

Comment: See this post, how to set scale on STL export in blender: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/scale-settings-for-exporting-to-stl-for-3d-printing

Answer (score 1):

Converted comment on OP to answer:

The comment links to a [question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7503/scale-settings-for-exporting-to-stl-for-3d-printing) on SE.Blender; the answer that led to the solution is quoted below.

> The STL exporter doesn't take Scene Scale into account. Import your
>   STL back into Blender (it will have the same size) and drag Scene
>   Scale up back to 1.0, and you'll see how the cube grows relative to
>   the grid.
>
> 1 Blender unit equals 1m, but STL seems to assume 1 unit as 1cm.
>
> If you want 1 unit to be 1mm, set Scale on STL export to 0.1 and 
>   Scene Scale to 0.001 to make it match the output scale in viewport.
>
> Note that the STL will be 10x smaller if you re-import it into
>   Blender!